# Command '-gcc' not found

Tags: gcc

Building an LFS for a school assignment got stuck on the gcc part of ch 5. I already checked to make sure that gcc is installed and ran `sudo apt install build-essential` and both are working properly. The command I'm tying to run is  `` cat gcc/limitx.h gcc/glimits.h gcc/limity.h > \ `dirname $($LFS_TGT-gcc -print-libgcc-file-name)`/install-tools/include/limits.h ``

I copy and pasted the code from the book, and the tutorial I'm following did the same. My best guess is that it's reading the `-gcc` part from  `LFS_TGT-gcc` but I could be wrong
'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFAQa.png)

Comment: You should have set up an *environment* in [4.4. Setting Up the Environment](https://linuxfromscratch.org/~bdubbs/lfs-book/chapter04/settingenvironment.html) that includes a `LFS_TGT` variable - if you didn't, then `$LFS_TGT` expands to an empty string, leaving just `-gcc`